# Pass html table in POST using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page and I need to send the contents of a table in a POST.
How do I capture the content of the table using jQuery and pass it to the server (which is running node.js and express.js)?
This is the example of a table in a page:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Test</title>
     <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table id=horarios>
      <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td>5 </td>
        <td>6 </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <form method=post>
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the server I would capture that POST with something like:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/mypage', function(req, res){
        var content = req.body;
        res.render('somepage');
});
```

Comment: Capture what exactly, other than a submit button, your form is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You want to send a POST request with body set to `$('#horarios').html()`

You can do this with [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType)

```
$.post(url, data, success, respType)
```

where `data` is the html string of your table, `success` is a callback if the server sends a success response, and `resType` is the type of data your server should send back (i.e. text, html, xml, json, script)

So for your example, try adding this inside a script tag on your html page:

```
// bind to form submit
$('form').submit(function(){

  // get table html
  var table = {html: $('#horarios').html()};

  // POST the data
  $.post('/mypage', table, function(response, textStatus){
    // do anything with the response here ...

  })
});
```

Comment: When do at the server: app.post('/mypage', function(req, res){
        var content = req.body;
        console.log(content);
}); I only get "{}" at the console. How do I recover the table data?

Comment: You might be using json parser middleware. It would be helpful to know what your express app setup looks like for this issue, but I think that's a separate question altogether.

Comment: Indeed, I am using ``body-parser``. ``var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
}));``Maybe I should convert the table to a json object before sending it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your table into a data structure. You can achieve this with:

```
 var tbl = $('#horarios tr').map(function(rowIdx, row) {
        var rowObj = $(row).find('td').map(function(cellIdx, cell) {
            var retVal = {};
            retVal['cell' + cellIdx] = cell.textContent.trim();
            return retVal;
        }).get();
        var retVal = {};
        retVal['row' + rowIdx] = rowObj;
        return retVal;
  }).get();
```

In this way you will pass the table as an array of rows of cells.

```js
$('input[value="Save"]').on('click', function(e) {
    //
    // prevent form submit
    //
    e.preventDefault();

    //
    // collect table data by row X col
    //
    var tbl = $('#horarios tr').map(function(rowIdx, row) {
        var rowObj = $(row).find('td').map(function(cellIdx, cell) {
            var retVal = {};
            retVal['cell' + cellIdx] = cell.textContent.trim();
            return retVal;
        }).get();
        var retVal = {};
        retVal['row' + rowIdx] = rowObj;
        return retVal;
    }).get();
    console.log('-->' + JSON.stringify({table: tbl}));
    $.post('/mypage', {table: tbl}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('success');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id=horarios>
    <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td>5 </td>
        <td>6 </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form method=post>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data to send via post, first you have to extract values from the table and i recommend you put it into an array, then send it via ajax post.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $dataElements = $('#horarios').find('td'),
      data = [];

    $.each($dataElements, function(i, elem){
        data.push($(elem).html());
    });

    $.ajax({url:'/mypage', method: 'POST', data: {data:JSON.stringify(data)}});
});
```

In other hand if you only want  to send the html just send it using `$('#horarios').html()` instead of loop through elements and add it to the post data.

I hope it helps...

Comment: I think there is a missing ``}`` at the end of the ``$.ajax`` line. How do I recover ``data`` on the server side? Tried ``console.log(req.body)`` but I only get ``{}`` as the response.

Comment: @PauloS.Abreu you are right, I already update the code. my approach help you?